# Did I alter the Unicode accidentally?

Tags: discussion, edits, revision-history

I thought I only removed the last sentence, but the edit history shows I modified other lines: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39511622/revisions

[Edit: same issue with https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33714827/revisions and https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40841796/revisions]

Is it because of my browser (Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS), or something else?

Comment: looks like you didn't altered anything. Don't look at the side by side. compare it with rev 1 and your edit.

Comment: @SagarV: just because it looks that way doesn't mean nothing changed..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, your submission removed some invisible characters. The original revision had some `\01` and `\05` (ASCII *Start of Header* and *Enquiry* characters), and they are gone from the revision you posted.

My text editor displays these differently, using SOH and ENQ blocks; here is a sample of the lines before and after:

[image]

They were probably removed by your browser, yes. They are not really bytes I'd expect to be preserved when editing in a *text editor*.

I wouldn't worry about it; they were not printable to begin with. If they are important, the OP should provide a hex dump or other representation of the data that is ASCII-safe.

Comment: Well, that question is about an issue due to "unexpect [characters]", so it is possible that these removed bytes are part of the problem. But yes, in that case the question should be edited to clarify that.

Comment: @Tom: well, the error basically contains random binary data. Exactly what binary data is perhaps less relevanvt.

Comment: I once set that up on purpose in a code golf cops and robbers. They didn't like it much.