# Editing a question that contains non-UTF8 characters □

Tags: bug, edits

Yesterday I edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47835021/json-parsing-string-unexpected-error) to improve code formatting.

At first there was nothing visibly wrong with the JSON however as I started editing I noticed `□` characters at the end which were causing the problem. I edited anyway ***without removing*** those invalid characters as I thought if I marked that JSON as code those invalid characters would show up in the question for everyone to see. This was not the case. Those characters got ***automagically*** removed. I of course edited my question again and added a comment that said not to approve my edit.

I'm wondering if this is a bug on SO? *(like @Amy mentioned in the comments)*

How was the OP able to post the question with those invalid characters when my edit was able to removed them ***automagically***?

Comment: I thought `□` would get removed in this question too, but apparently not...

Comment: Could someone undo the damage Hassan Imam did on that post?

Comment: what a mess ... I added a screenshot ... I should have tested in the sandbox .. sorry about that.

Comment: potentially related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352184/did-i-alter-the-unicode-accidentally

Comment: □ is U+25A1: WHITE SQUARE, a perfectly normal Unicode character, like any other. It can be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32, like any other Unicode character.

Comment: Weird. They don't even show up at the end of the Markdown when you view the editing history.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand The actual problem characters in the original version of the post were ASCII/Unicode BEL (CTRL-G) characters. They can also be encoded in UTF-8, etc. but apparently something is deleting them automatically anyways.